# CSS messing up on iPad browsers

Tags: ios, css, ipad, sass

I have some scss that I'm trying to use for an app. It works fine on my laptop's Firefox/Chrome/Safari browsers but blanks the page on an iPad's Safari/Chrome. I think it's related to the transform properties? Here's my code:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none; /* Remove default numbering */
    *list-style: decimal; /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);

    ol {
      margin: 0 0 0 2em; /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
    }
}

.rounded-list{
  a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .7em .7em .7em 2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: $light-gray-1;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    /*transition: all .2s ease-out; Uncomment here to add fade-in/out effect*/
      &:hover {
        background: $light-gray-2;
      }
      &:hover:before {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -ms-transform: scaleX(-1); /* IE 9 */
      }
      &:before {
        content: counter(li);
        counter-increment: li;
        position: absolute; 
        left: -1.3em;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -1em;
        background: #87ceeb;
        height: 2em;
        width: 2em;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        border: .3em solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 2em;
        transition: all .3s ease-out;
      }
  } 
}
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<ol class="rounded-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Any ideas as to why this would blank out an iPad's browser??

Comment: meta tags are there or not?

Comment: I'm using Foundation css with Rails 4, so ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` is already set.